# Connect to JBoss AS 7 on Oracle Linux 7 in VirtualBox

Tags: java, linux, oracle, jboss

I installed the Oracle Linux 7 in to the VirtualBox. This is a standard installation, I did not configure anything.
The virtual machine network is attached to Bridged Adapter.

> [root@localhost ~]# /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup ifcfg-enp0s3
>
> Connection successfully activated (D-Bus active path: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0)
>
> [root@localhost ~]# ip addr
>
> 2: enp0s3:  mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
>       link/ether 08:00:27:ad:4f:68 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
>       inet 172.24.131.35/24 brd 172.24.131.255 scope global enp0s3
>       inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fead:4f68/64 scope link
>          valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

With winscp I copied the jboss-as-7 and the java to /usr/etc path.

> [root@localhost ~]# export JAVA_HOME="/usr/etc/jdk1.7.0_67"
>
> [root@localhost ~]# export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
>
> [root@localhost ~]# java -version

-bash: /usr/etc/jdk1.7.0_67/bin/java: Permission denied

> [root@localhost ~]# chmod u+x /usr/etc/jdk1.7.0_67/bin/java
>   [root@localhost ~]# java -version

java version "1.7.0_67"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)

> [root@localhost ~]# chmod u+x /usr/etc/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/standalone.sh
>
> [root@localhost ~]# /usr/etc/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/standalone.sh

...

> 08:46:30,919 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-2) Initializing Mojarra 2.1.7-jbossorg-1 (20120227-1401) for context '/MyExample'
>
> 08:46:32,269 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /MyExample
>
> 08:46:32,369 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "MyExample.war"

After this, I tried to connect with my Host machine to the Guest server with this link http:// 172.24.131.35 : 8080/MyExample/
But it is not connect.

What could be wrong? In the Linux or in the standalone.xml? Or my virtual machine installation in VirtualBox?

The JBoss AS 7 is a standard install too.

[Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/827503/44ums/jbossas7_virtualboxoracle7_log.txt) is the console log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to connect from external machines (which is your Host now) you need to set `jboss.bind.address` to your IP or to `0.0.0.0`. So run it likes this

```
sh standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0
```

Now you should be to connect to your server remotely.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the firewall on the Oracle Linux 7.

So i had to stop and disable firewalld using systemd.

systemctl stop firewalld.service
systemctl disable firewalld.service

Thanks,
ed

Comment: In addition to this, you'd need to configure jboss to listen to all interfaces (like instructed by Petr Mensik) and also have port forwarding set up on virtualbox.